# silverlight business application login cannot connect to database

Tags: silverlight, authentication

I'm at my wits end. I built a silverlight business application using the template and I tried and played around with the login functionality in the IIS express. Everything works perfect, but when I moved the application to the IIS server, the login suddenly giving me this error.

[image: This error]

I have given the remote access to sql server, 
I tried to give access even ceremoniously given IISAPPPOOLS\ account ownership access, yet I still have this problem.

Oh yeah, I have not give database restriction yet to the application, but the other data is showing up real well. except for the login information.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be a Network issue it unable to locate the server that is running SQL server i would check the connection string and include the fully qualified address of the server running SQL server